# Is it possible for lxml to work in a case-insensitive manner?

Tags: python, css-selectors, lxml, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

I'm trying to scrape META keywords and description tags from arbitrary websites. I obviusly have no control over said website, so have to take what I'm given. They have a variety of casings for the tag and attributes, which means I need to work case-insensitively. I can't believe that the lxml authors are as stubborn as to insist on full forced standards-compliance when it excludes much of the use of their library.

I'd like to be able to say `doc.cssselect('meta[name=description]')` (or some XPath equivalent) but this will not catch `<meta name="Description" Content="...">` tags due othe captial D.

I'm currently using this as a workaround, but it's horrible!

```
for meta in doc.cssselect('meta'):
    name = meta.get('name')
    content = meta.get('content')

    if name and content:
        if name.lower() == 'keywords':
            keywords = content
        if name.lower() == 'description':
            description = content
```

It seems that the tag name `meta` is treated case-insensitively, but the attributes are not. It would be even more annoying `meta` was case-sensitive too!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Values* of attributes *must* be case-sensitive.

You can use arbitrary regular expression to select an element:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from lxml import html

doc = html.fromstring('''
    <meta name="Description">
    <meta name="description">
    <META name="description">
    <meta NAME="description">
''')
for meta in doc.xpath('//meta[re:test(@name, "^description$", "i")]',
                      namespaces={"re": "http://exslt.org/regular-expressions"}):
    print html.tostring(meta, pretty_print=True),
```

Output:

```
<meta name="Description">
<meta name="description">
<meta name="description">
<meta name="description">
```

Answer (score 2):

lxml is an XML parser.  XML is case-sensitive.  You are parsing HTML, so you should use an HTML parser.  BeautifulSoup is very popular.  Its only drawback is that it can be slow.

Comment: `lxml.html`, `lxml.html.soupparser`, and `lxml.html.html5parser` provide HTML parsers.

Comment: BeautifulSoup barfs on the markup in a lot of pages, particularly with Javascript containing strings with tags inside them. lxml does not, hence why I wanted to use lxml.

Comment: @Mat: [Beautiful Soup 4 can use `lxml` as a parser](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser).

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```py
doc.cssselect.xpath("//meta[translate(@name,
    'ABCDEFGHJIKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghjiklmnopqrstuvwxyz')='description']")
```

It translates the value of "name" to lowercase and then matches.

See also:

- [XPath: How do you do a lowercase call in xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965529/xpath-how-do-you-do-a-lowercase-call-in-xpath)
- [Xpath translation function turns things into lowercase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852012/xpath-translation-function-turns-things-into-lowercase)

Comment: wouldn't you only need to translate the letter in 'description' (or whatever the value you're comparing to is)? ...`"//meta[translate(@name, 'DESCRIPTON', 'descripton')='description']"`