# XPath: How do you do a lowercase call in xpath

Tags: html, xpath

I'm using Firefox's XPath-checker and can't get the syntax right. I have a link:

```
<a>LinkName</a>
```

and I try doing:

```
//a[lower-case(child::text())='linkname']
```

but I have a syntax error. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 46, accepted):

There is no function called `lower-case` in XPath 1.0 which is the version of XPath used in Firefox.

You need to use the ugly `translate` function instead:-

```
  translate(text(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
```

...but of course you would need to extend this if you need coverage of a wider character-set.

Comment: Great hint - not only applicable to Firefox :)

Comment: Note: "translate" should be lower-cased.

Comment: Here is the complete ANSI table: translate(%s, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞŸŽŠŒ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿžšœ')

Comment: Used it in my java code as `nodeRev = (NodeList) xPath.compile("//StandardDetail/IsReverseEvent[translate(text(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')='true']").evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);`

Answer (score 0):

You can Use Translate

```
//a[translate(text(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') = 'linkname']
```