# How to find element by multiple text strings?

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I was curious if there was a way to find an element using Selenium and Python 2.7 by multiple "keywords" in any order. Allow me to explain using an example:

```
keyword1 = raw_input("Keyword: ").lower().title()
keyword2 = raw_input("Keyword: ").lower().title()

    try :
        clickOnProduct = "driver.find_element_by_xpath(\"//*[contains(text(), '" + keyword1 + "')]\").click()"
        exec(clickOnProduct)
```

This is just a snippet of the code, but how could I incorporate this to look for an element that contains both of these keywords (**keyword1, keyword2**) in any order? It sounds easy in principle and it probably is, but I am having a hell of a time trying to get this. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can dynamically construct the XPath expression using `or` and `contains()`:

```
keywords = [keyword1, keyword2, ... ]
conditions = " or ".join(["contains(., '%s')" % keyword for keyword in keywords])
expression = "//*[%s]" % conditions

elm = driver.find_element_by_xpath(expression)
```

If, for example, `keyword1` would be `hello` and `keyword2` would be `world`, the `expression` would become:

```
//*[contains(., 'hello') or contains(., 'world')]
```

If you want to also handle both lower and upper case, you would need to use `translate()`, see more in this relevant thread:

- [How to find all elements containing the word "download" using Selenium x-path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33832164/how-to-find-all-elements-containing-the-word-download-using-selenium-x-path)

Comment: I still seem to be having trouble. The expression looks like this: 
`//*[contains(., 'Coat') or contains(., 'Car')]` but it still can't find an element that contains the text "Car Coat".

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much, was a simple mistake on my part. I fixed my problem by changing `".join(["contains(., '%s')"` to `.join(["contains(text(), '%s')"`. Thanks for the help!