# Is it possible for BeautifulSoup to work in a case-insensitive manner?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract Meta Description for fetched webpages. But here I am facing the problem of case sensitivity of BeautifulSoup.

As some of the pages have `<meta name="Description` and some have `<meta name="description`.

My problem is very much similar to that of [Question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734125/is-it-possible-for-lxml-to-work-in-a-case-insensitive-manner)

The only difference is that I can't use lxml .. I have to stick with Beautifulsoup.

Comment: For those that *can* switch from `html` to `xml` there is an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12163802/778533

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With minor changes it works.

```
soup.findAll('meta', attrs={'name':re.compile("^description$", re.I)})
```

Answer (score 19):

You can give BeautifulSoup a regular expression to match attributes against.  Something like

```
soup.findAll('meta', name=re.compile("^description$", re.I))
```

might do the trick.  Cribbed from [the BeautifulSoup docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Searching%20the%20Parse%20Tree).

Comment: Note, for this to work you'll also need to import regular expressions with this line at the top:
`import re`

Answer (score 17):

A regular expression? Now we have [another problem](http://xkcd.com/1171/).

Instead, you can pass in a lambda:

```
soup.findAll(lambda tag: tag.name.lower()=='meta',
    name=lambda x: x and x.lower()=='description')
```

(`x and` avoids an exception when the `name` attribute isn't defined for the tag)

Comment: Using bs4 i'm getting "find_all() got multiple values for keyword argument 'name'" with that :/

Comment: @Joaolvcm “You [can’t use](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-keyword-arguments) a keyword argument to search for HTML’s ‘name’ element, because Beautiful Soup uses the name argument to contain the name of the tag itself. Instead, you can give a value to ‘name’ in the attrs argument.” TL;DR: `soup.find_all(lambda tag: ..., {"name": lambda x: ...})`.

Answer (score 7):

With bs4 use the following:

```
soup.find('meta', attrs={'name': lambda x: x and x.lower()=='description'})
```

Answer (score 3):

Better still use a css [attribute = value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) selector with `i` argument for case insensitivity

```
soup.select('meta[name="description" i]')
```

Answer (score -6):

change case of the html page source. Use functions such as string.lower(), string.upper()

Comment: why do you think so

Comment: and i am not asking question. i am answering the question