# How to maintain case-sensitive tags in BeautifulSoup.BeautifulStoneSoup?

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I am writing a script that edits an XML file with `BeautifulStoneSoup`, but the library converts all tags to lower case. Is there an option to conserve the case?

```
import BeautifulSoup    
xml = "<TestTag>a string</TestTag>"    
soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulStoneSoup(xml, markupMassage=False)    
print soup.prettify() # or soup.renderContents()
#prints
>>> <testtag>a string</testtag> 
#instead of the expected
>>> <TestTag>a string</TestTag>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could use [Beautiful Soup 4](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#parsing-xml), as follows (requires the lxml XML library):

```
In [10]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [11]: xml = "<TestTag>a string</TestTag>"

In [12]: soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, "xml")

In [13]: print soup
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TestTag>a string</TestTag>

In [14]:
```

Comment: Thanks, made the upgrade and it works great. For future readers: run `pip install BeautifulSoup4` not `pip install beautifulsoup --upgrade`

Comment: Worth mentioning that it requires the `xml` library, not `lxml` which is what beautifulsoup recommends if you run it with no specification. `lxml` does not maintain case.

Comment: @KeithSmiley: Yes, when using `soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, "lxml")`, lxml's HTML parser is used. See http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser.

Comment: I have `BeautifulSoup4` installed on `Win7` but it didn't come with `lxml`. Here is a post on the trouble I encountered on getting it installed:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40640026/how-to-install-module-for-beautifulsoup-xml-parsing?noredirect=1#comment68512605_40640026