# beautifulsoup Case Insensitive?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I was reading: [Is it possible for BeautifulSoup to work in a case-insensitive manner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602390/is-it-possible-for-beautifulsoup-to-work-in-a-case-insensitive-manner)

But it's not what I actually needed, I'm looking for all `img` tags in webpage, which include: `IMG, Img etc...`

This code:

```
images = soup.findAll('img')
```

Will only look for `img` tags case sensitive so how can I solve this problem without adding new line for every single possibility (and maybe forget to add some)?

Please Note that the above question isn't about the tag but it's properties.

Comment: What's the URL?

Comment: @baduker how is my problem related to a specific url? I want to find tags case insensitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BeautifulSoup` *is not case sensitiv per se* just give it a try. If you miss some information in your result maybe there is another issue. You could force it to parse sensitiv while using `xml` parser if needed in some case.

**Note:** *In newer code avoid old syntax `findAll()` instead use `find_all()` - For more take a minute to [check docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names)*

###### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '''
<img src="" alt="lower">
<IMG src="" alt="upper">
<iMG src="" alt="mixed">
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

soup.find_all('img')
```

###### Output

```
[<img alt="lower" src=""/>,
 <img alt="upper" src=""/>,
 <img alt="mixed" src=""/>]
```