# Xpath translation function turns things into lowercase?

Tags: xpath

I am using xpath's translation function to remove some characters in a string but it also converts all the letters into lower case. Is this supposed to happen? How can I change this behavior.

Comment: How about some code that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: As proof by @Dimitre's answer this is a not reproducible problem for `fn:translate()`. Unless you provide an example this is not a real question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard XPath function:

```
translate($someString, $chars-to-be-replaced, $replacement-chars)
```

produces a new string in which a character from `$someString` is changed only it is one of the characters in the second argument -- `$chars-to-be-replaced`.

**From the [XPath 1.0 W3C specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-translate)**:

> Function: string translate(string,
>   string, string)
>
> The **[translate function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-translate)**
>   returns the first argument string with
>   occurrences of characters in the
>   second argument string replaced by the
>   character at the corresponding
>   position in the third argument string.
>   For example,
>   `translate("bar","abc","ABC")` returns
>   the string `BAr`. If there is a
>   character in the second argument
>   string with no character at a
>   corresponding position in the third
>   argument string (because the second
>   argument string is longer than the
>   third argument string), then
>   occurrences of that character in the
>   first argument string are removed. For
>   example,
>   `translate("--aaa--","abc-","ABC")`
>   returns `"AAA"`. If a character occurs
>   more than once in the second argument
>   string, then the first occurrence
>   determines the replacement character.
>   If the third argument string is longer
>   than the second argument string, then
>   excess characters are ignored.

**Therefore, the problem you have is in the code that you haven't shown.**

Comment: You are right, I messed something up. Guess I should have done more research first