# Case Insensitive XML parsing in Python Element Tree

Tags: xml, python-2.7, xml-parsing, elementtree

I need to parse and get the specific attribute for the given attribute from the XML by using findall function in Element Tree lib. 
For Example,

```
<Mapping>
<Map name="map1" sys_id="QAE567-hKLO890" path="\\sys1\map1\" uuid="EL8976-hF056" />
<Map name="map2" sys_id="RTY897-RT643DF" path="\\sys2\map2\" uuid="Jkl56W-yKP87" />
...
...
...
</Mapping>
```

We using following query to get the 'sys_id' and 'path' attribute for given uuid from the xml, but in some cases we are providing uuid with different case 'el8976-hf056' instead of 'EL8976-hF056'. In this case we are not able to get the path and sys_id of that uuid.

```
Elms = root.findall(".//Mapping/Map[@uuid='%s']" % "el8976-hf056")
```

How can we get the exact path and sys_id with correct case ?

Answer (score 1):

If the value in your XML is always in upper-case, you can just convert the provided `uuid` to upper-case first :

```
Elms = root.findall(".//Mapping/Map[@uuid='%s']" % "el8976-hf056".upper())
```

or use [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/installation.html) library if you really need to fiter the attribute value in case-insensitive way, as shown in the following thread : [Is it possible for lxml to work in a case-insensitive manner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734125/is-it-possible-for-lxml-to-work-in-a-case-insensitive-manner)

**update :**

Using `ElementTree` you'll need to implement the case-insensitive checking logic in python:

1. Loop through `root.findall(".//Mapping/Map")`
2. Inside the `for` loop body, check the corresponding `uuid` attribute value case-insensitively and take action accordingly. For reference: [How do I do a case insensitive string comparison in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319426/how-do-i-do-a-case-insensitive-string-comparison-in-python)

Comment: uuid is mixed of lower and upper case. Is it possible to do this in Element Tree ?

Comment: @Venkatesh see **update** section for guidance on how to do this using `ElementTree`